# SQL Management Studio 2008 authentication error

Tags: sql-server

I have just installed SQL Server 2008. Now it's not proceeding. It stuck at the beginning screen which is Connect to server. It is asking me to type server name. I don't know this; what should I do next?

[image]

Comment: Did you take the tour? try to write `.` .

Comment: Type the server name. Or it may be available from the drop-down (click the arrow).

Comment: I checked the drop down.. there is an option "browse for more" but when i click on it.. there is nothing :(

Comment: Please do not ask volunteers for urgent help - mostly helpful people are here in their spare time, and they will answer questions they like, at their leisure. Your deadlines are your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you installed SQL Server on the same computer that you're trying to connect from, and I'll also (dangerously) assume that it's a legitimate - probably free - installation.

If it's an Express (Free) Edition, the default instance name should be SQLExpress, which means you would type in:

```
Server: .\SQLExpress
```

or

```
Server: (local)\SQLExpress
```

or

```
Server: <your computer's name>\SQLExpress
```

You can leave it on "Windows Authentication" and try to connect.

Comment: Thankyou so much.. as u said type server: .\SQL Express i did it and it worked. thnkyou so muchh once again :)

Comment: Any time.  Just happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps:

1. Log on to the box where you have installed SQL Server 2008.
2. Run SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) as administrator
3. When it asks for Server Name then put . in it (with a dot . SQL Server will consider local installation) and then enter as windows authentication
4. If you are successful in above step run a new query (or press CTRL+N) and execute this query: **select  @@SERVERNAME** the output of this query is your server, which you should have put in the ServerName text box.
5. If you are unsuccessful in step 3, that means you have a named instance installed, to find this out; open SQL Server Configuration Manager from Windows, All programs SQL Server 2008 and Configuration tools and check the instance name. It appears as **SQL Server (YourInstanceName)**, Now you know what to put in your Server Name textbox whic is going to be .\YourInstnaceName. One your are connected to the server then repeat step 4 to check its proper path for remote login.